# Java Stream custom list based on List

Tags: java, list, java-stream, pojo

I have seen many examples of streaming a java custom list, e.g. `List<People>`, to filter for a single value, e.g.

`p -> p.Name.contains("john")`.  (People pojo has a few properties: `Name`, `Age`, `Sex`).

I want to actually stream without filtering on a single value but filtering on a list of strings, i.e.Instead of just "John", I can provide a list of items to filter against.

e.g. Pseudo: `p -> p.Name.contains(List<String>)`

I am hoping this is simple to explain without need for code.

Any ideas?

Comment: `p -> list.contains(p.name)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`List::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) to filter using a list of Strings:

```
List<People> people = Arrays.asList(
        new People("John", 25, "M"),
        new People("Jane", 25, "F"),
        new People("Pete", 25, "M"),
        new People("Albert", 25, "M"),
        new People("Victor", 25, "M")
);

List<String> names = Arrays.asList("John", "Pete", "Victor");

List<People> filtered = people.stream()
        .filter(p -> names.contains(p.getName())) // if the name of p is contained in the list of string names to filter
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

```
People{name='John', age=25, sex='M'}, 
People{name='Pete', age=25, sex='M'}, 
People{name='Victor', age=25, sex='M'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest and simplest option is to utilize the `contains` method of the list as suggested by others.

Athough you could also do:

```
.filter(p -> namesList.stream().anyMatch(name -> name.equals(p.getName())))
...
```

or to be slightly more consisting with the other answer, you could change the above to:

```
.filter(p -> namesList.stream().anyMatch(name -> Objects.equals(name, p.getName())))
...
```

Thus, avoiding `NPE` when `namesList` contains `null` elements.

---

That aside, if you're going to proceed with  `.filter(p -> namesList.contains(p.getName()))` then I'd suggest you change the collection containing the names from a `List` to a `Set` implementation as the `contains` method will perform much better with a `Set` than with a `List` implementation.

This is of course if and only if it's appropriate to do so without causing performance deficit elsewhere.